# Firebase notifications only showing up in control center

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm facing this weird issue with a new project I've setup using firebase. Notifications are working, however there are two main issues I've noticed:

1. They never appear as a banner that pops-down when my phone is on/home screen, instead they only appear when viewing all my notifications in the notification center (swiping all the way left from home)
2. I can't get them to play a sound (adding a badge does indeed work).

Additionally, I tried this from both the firebase admin sdk (web, node js), and from their "Cloud Messaging" wizard - both with the same results, leading me to think its something I've set incorrectly in my project?

Here is how I register for notifications:

```
func requestNotificationsSystemAuth() {
        let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = appDelegate as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = appDelegate as MessagingDelegate

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: { _, _ in })
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
```

Other apps are playing sound in notifications.

Any idea?? I'm losing hope!

Answer (score 0):

For those who were wondering, my issue was device related weirdly enough.

I just restarted my phone, and it started working again.